# Вк плеер принцип, почему не перезагружается и сохраняет свое положение

Tags: history, javascript, html5, вконтакте, плеер

Вк плеер при переходе на другие страницы того же сайта не перезагружается, а сохраняет свое положение и продолжает играть. Как это реализовано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите [localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) для исследования взаимодействия между страницами, открытыми в одном браузере (в закладках, например).

Смотрите [history api](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) для понимания того, как в пределах домена переходить разными путями в url'е без перезагрузки страницы, и соответственно прерыва проигрывания.

Answer (score 0):

Просто сайт ВК это сайт RIA. Вы всегда находитесь на одной и тойже странице. Все данные загружаються AJAX-ом, например.